# How to set a default value to an argument in a programatically defined schema?

Tags: graphql-js

I can't seem to find how to do it in the official GraphQL documentation.

A (very) simple example:

```
let PostType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'post',
    description: 'Represents a blog post',
    fields() {
       return {
           title: {
               type: GraphQLString,
               args: {
                   id: {
                      // HOW CAN I MAKE THIS ARG (id) OPTIONAL
                      // OR SET A DEFAULT VALUE TO IT?
                      type: GraphQLString
                    }
               }
           }
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlobjecttype):

```
type GraphQLArgumentConfig = {
  type: GraphQLInputType;
  defaultValue?: any;
  description?: ?string;
}
```

So in addition to a `type`, just define a `defaultValue` for that argument.